# Displaying a property of a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to display a property (myCar.Make) on a web form using the simpliest way, e.g. a literal control.

But I get errors.

How to do achieve this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Car myCar = new Car();
    myCar.Make = "BMW";
    myCar.Model = "745li";
    myCar.Color = "Black";
    myCar.Year = 2005;

    Literal1.Text = "Car Make: {0}", myCar.Make;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to format your string, but you need to call `String.Format()` to get it to work:

```
 Literal1.Text = String.Format("Car Make: {0}", myCar.Make);
```

Comment: Because "Car Make: {0}" is simply a string literal... You're looking to process that string and `String.Format()` is the function that does that for you. You've probably picked up that syntax on the internet or seeing it used with `Console.WriteLine()`: ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
Literal1.Text = "Car Make: " + myCar.Make;
```

or

```
Literal1.Text = string.Format("Car Make: {0}", myCar.Make);
```

Comment: Thanks, I wanted the Car Make: {0} format as answered above.

Comment: @BlancoBluesman: Sorry I didn't get you? this does show how to `use string.format()`?